# Разбор url nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть url: `http://ip/deberc/js/main.js`

**deberc** - название игры. Есть задача на основе этого названия подключать конфиги:

```
include /home/$gameName/nginx/*.conf;
```

То есть, задача — в переменную $gameName засунуть deberc

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: set $gameName deberc; кажется

Comment: не плохо, это нужно достать из url http://ip/deberc/js/main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ориентируясь на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158834/4827341), например, можно так:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)/ ) {
  include /home/$1/nginx/*.conf;
}
```

правда, я не уверен, что `.*` не «вберёт» в себя и другие части *url* вместе со слэшами. если «вберёт», попробуйте, например, так:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ ^/([^/]+)/ ) {
```

---

если требуется только присвоить значение переменной, то замените:

```
  include /home/$1/nginx/*.conf;
```

на:

```
  set $gameName $1;
```